# Type UIRectCorner has no member isRightPage in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

We have the following variable of type UIImage that no longer works in Swift 3. Is there anyone with this same issue facing with UIImage class in such a way. Here is the code:

```
var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            var corners: UIRectCorner = isRightPage ? .TopRight | .BottomRight : .TopLeft | .BottomLeft
            imageView.image = image!.imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize(bounds.size).imageWithRoundedCornersSize(20, corners: corners)
        }
    }
```

The error we're getting is "Type of expression is ambigouos without more context" for `var corners: UIRectCorner = isRightPage ? .TopRight | .BottomRight : .TopLeft | .BottomLeft`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually getting the `int` value from the enum therefore the statement was failing.

Try this:

```
var corners: UIRectCorner = UIRectCorner(rawValue: isRightPage ? (UIRectCorner.topRight.rawValue | UIRectCorner.bottomRight.rawValue) : (UIRectCorner.topLeft.rawValue | UIRectCorner.bottomLeft.rawValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2 introduced a new type, `OptionSet`, for handling sets of flags. You can combine multiple flags using literal array notation (`[a, b, c]`) instead of using bitwise operators like `|`.

The [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/), introducing during Swift 3's development, say that only type and protocol names begin with an upper case letter, and everything else starts with a lower-case letter. The iOS 10 API was changed to follow the guidelines.

So define `corners` like this:

```
let corners: UIRectCorner = isRightPage ? [.topRight, .bottomRight] : [.topLeft, .bottomLeft]
```